# A porcentagem me retorna zero no c#

Tags: c#, porcentagem

Quando os resultados são impressos, a porcentagem de homens e mulheres entrevistados e pessoas com renda até 500 reias dão igual a zero.

```
        `string nome;
        char sexo, estado_civil;
        int idade, cont = 0, cont_m = 0, cont_f = 0, cont_media = 0, cont_renda_500 = 0, cont_renda_f = 0;
        double renda, menor_renda_m = double.MaxValue, maior_renda_f = double.MinValue, media = 0, rendamedia = 0, porce_m, porce_f, porce_dois;

        while (cont < 5)
        {
            ++cont;
            Console.Write("Digite o seu nome: (FLAG = 0)");
            nome = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Digite o seu sexo:");
            sexo = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
            Console.Write("Digite o seu estado civil:(S = solteiro / C = Casado / D = Divorciado)");
            estado_civil = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
            Console.Write("Digite a seu idade:");
            idade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite a sua renda:");
            renda = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (sexo == 'F') {
                cont_f++;
                if (renda > maior_renda_f && estado_civil == 'S')
                {
                    maior_renda_f = renda;
                }
                if (estado_civil == 'S' && idade < 25 && renda < 3200)
                {
                    cont_renda_f++;
                }
            }
            else if (sexo == 'M') {
                cont_m++;
                if (renda < menor_renda_m && estado_civil == 'C')
                {
                    menor_renda_m = renda;
                }
            }
            if (idade >= 30 && idade <= 40)
            {
                rendamedia += renda;
                cont_media++;
            }
            if (renda <= 500)
            {
                cont_renda_500++;
            }
        }

            porce_f = (cont_f / cont) * 100;
            porce_m = (cont_m / cont) * 100;
            media = rendamedia / cont_media;
            porce_dois = (cont_renda_500 / cont) * 100;
            Console.WriteLine("Porcentagem de mulheres entrevistadas: " + porce_f.ToString("0.00") + "%");
            Console.WriteLine("Porcentagem de homens entrevistados: " + porce_m.ToString("0.00") + "%");
            Console.WriteLine("Maior renda entre mulheres solteiras: " + maior_renda_f.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("Menor renda entre homens casados " + menor_renda_m.ToString("C"));
            Console.WriteLine("Renda média das pessoas com a idade entre 30 e 40 anos: " + media.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Mulheres solteiras com idade inferior a 25 anos e ganham até 3200 reais: " + cont_renda_f);
            Console.WriteLine("Porcentagem de pessoas com renda até 500 reais: " + porce_dois.ToString("0.00" + "%"));
            Console.ReadKey();`
```

Comment: Palpite: ambas as variáveis `cont_renda_500` e `cont` são inteiras, então acredito que a parte decimal da divisão é desconsiderada para que o resultado também seja inteiro. Já tentou converter um valor para `double` antes da divisão?

Comment: Quais são os dados entrados, e os resultados esperados? Tem como você fazer um [mcve]? Além do que o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou, tem outras coisas que podem influir já que tem algumas coisas são bem ingênuas no código, funciona se tudo estiver certo. Ajuda criar confusão aquele emaranhado de variáveis no começo do código.

Comment: @bigown as entradas podem ser aleatórias, o restante dos resultados estão corretos porém ao pedir a porcentagem ele me retorna 0.

Comment: @MareMads não foi isso que eu falei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está fazendo a operação com inteiros. Para se obter a porcentagem sempre faça a divisão por um `double` ou `float`.

Exemplo:

```
(cont_f / (double)cont) * 100
```

Caso você queira fazer o arredondamento utilize a classe Math com um dos métodos de arredondamento como o Math.Round() ou Math.Ceiling() ou Math.Floor()

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Comment: Eu que agradeço, se a resposta foi útil, por favor, de um upvote e marque como aceita ;)

Comment: Legal negativar, mas por favor me indique o erro para que eu possa corrir ou se for o caso até remover a minha resposta caso a mesma esteja completamente errado